# Self Relationship Level Limit

Tags: relationships

Is there a way to limit the number of levels a Self Relationship may go to?  I have a self relationship on An Activity List Object which can have a parent Activity List but I don't want to allow endless levels.

Comment: You mean one activity list can have only one parent activity list?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Is there a way of limiting the number or level deep.

Comment: Have a look, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7282/how-to-create-a-one-to-one-relation-between-two-objects

Answer (score 0):

You create a validation rule for checking parent.parent == null other wise do not allow save the record.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two fields on your activity, let's call them `p2c__c` for a look-up for the parent to child activity and another called `c2P__c` which is a look-up to the parent from the child activity, you could create a validation rule on activity using those two fields.

If you only want to allow 1 level, then you'd need to specify that on the parent's record, `c2p__c != null && new record's c2p__c == record Id of parent`. If true, an error message would be generated and the record couldn't be saved. If false, you could save and insert the record.

If you want to allow 2 levels, then in addition to above, you'd need to specify that on grandparent's record, `c2p__c != null && p2c__c != recordId of parent's c2p__c record Id`. If the above evaluates to true (we want the latter to be equal to recordId of parent record), a new record wouldn't be allowed to save and an error message would be displayed. If false, then you could save a new record.

In essence, you'd need to keep repeating the above logic sequence for each additional level you want to allow.